# geom_historgram() versus hist() : controlling ranges in geom

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Consider the following two plots

```
 library(ggplot2)
 set.seed(666)
 bigx <- data.frame(x=sample(1:12,50,replace=TRUE))

 ggplot(bigx, aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_histogram(fill = "red", colour =         
                   "black",stat="bin",binwidth=2) +
    ylab("Frequency") +
    xlab("things") +
    ylim(c(0,30))

 hist(bigx$x)
```

[image]

[image]

Why do I get the overhang above 12 on ggplot? When i play with `right = TRUE` this just shifts the overhang to below zero. I want the simple and simply bounded result from `hist()` but using `ggplot2`.

How can I do this?

Comment: looks the same to me. change the `binwidth=1` and look at `hist(bigx$x, breaks = 15, ylim = c(0,30), col = 'red')`

Comment: thanks for looking all I do not see ow they look the same. I want geom to look like hist though not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to reproduce the output of `hist(...)` using `ggplot`, this will work:

```
ggplot(bigx, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "red", colour = "black",stat="bin",
                 binwidth=2, right=TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,12),breaks=seq(0,12,2))
```

[image]

Or, more generally, this:

```
brks <- hist(bigx$x, plot=F)$breaks
ggplot(bigx, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "red", colour = "black",stat="bin",
                 breaks=brks, right=TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=range(brks),breaks=brks)
```

Evidently, the `ggplot` default for histograms is to use right-closed intervals, whereas the default for `hist(...)` is left closed intervals. Also, `ggplot` uses a different algorithm for calculating the x-axis breaks and limits.